# Positive definite solution of Homogeneous Lyapunov equation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, control-theory, linear-control

Find the necessary and sufficient condition to find the positive definite matrix $X$ to satisfy the equation $AX=XA^{*}$ where $A$ is the given matrix whose spectrum is closed under complex conjugation.

Comment: I'm not sure Lyapunov theory applies here. The problem sets $Q = 0$, which is not positive definite.

Comment: I have found its solution. This is possible if and only if the matrix $A$ is a diagonalizable matrix with real eigenvalues.